# Forgot password in .Net Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity, claims

my login and register methods are working well and i use the `Claim` when the user try to login or logout.
i saw many example of that ForgotMyPassword page but all of it using
 `private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;`  which is based on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;` . Can i do ForgotMyPassword action without using `UserManager`
?? im asking that `Claim` based authentication and authorization is what i need in my project.
can i use them both,if i can how can i do that ?
it would be so great if someone explain its clearly,regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users register, their information will be added to the database. You can pass the registered email of the user to the ForgotMyPassword action. Then send a verification code to the mailbox or send a link to make user redirect to another page to reset the password. Make the user finish changing the password.

[image]

You can both use authentication and authorization, they are responsible for different businesses. Authentication has cookie, jwt and other authentication service. cookie authentication is the built-in component. Identity has integrated it. You should have learn about it.

The another service is authorization. Authorization service only works after authentication is successful. It has many authorization methods, about claim-based authorization, when one user access the authorized action, it will go through the middleware `app.UseAuthorization()`. This middleware will check whether there is a claim corresponding to the action policy's claim. Because you have configured it in startup.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options=>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Policy1",policy=>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim("claim1",new string[] {"value1","value2" });
            });
        });
```

On the authorized action.

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "Policy1")]
    public IActionResult get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

In this scenario, the user should have the claim `Claim("claim1","value1")` or `Claim("claim1","value2")`.